# How do I remove null columns in my following complex MySQL query

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, null

My MYSQL query is fairly complex and I want to remove the null columns from it

```
SELECT NamazTiming.FajarZamat,MasjidMaster.MasjidID_PK,MasjidMaster.MasjidName,MasjidMaster.Longitude,MasjidMaster.Latitude,MasjidMaster.Address,
    SQRT( POW( 69.1 * (MasjidMaster.Latitude - 19.8) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * (75.4- MasjidMaster.Longitude) * COS(MasjidMaster.Latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance ,CityMaster.CityName
    FROM MasjidMaster
    LEFT JOIN CityMaster
    ON MasjidMaster.CityID_FK = CityMaster.CityID_PK
    LEFT JOIN NamazTiming 
    ON  MasjidMaster.MasjidID_PK = NamazTiming.MasjidID_FK 
    HAVING distance < 10
    ORDER BY NamazTiming.FajarZamat
```

The Null columns are of NamazTiming.FajarZamat

Comment: You could either just remove the columns from the select list or wrap those columns with a `IFNULL(ColumnName,'defaultValue')` statement.

Comment: "Remove the null columns" as in make the values not null or "remove the null columns" as in "don't return the records that have null for column ____"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should add the following to your query before the ORDER BY. This would remove all the rows where that column is null.

```
WHERE NamazTiming.FajarZamat IS NOT NULL
```